# Combine all the lines of a text file into a single line via the Windows Command line

Tags: command-line, script, batch-file, text-formatting

I wrote a command line script that makes a list of files I want to do things to such as compress, delete or email. The list would be in the following format:

```
7z-Compression-List.txt:
========================

file1
file2
file3
etc...
```

For compression, I want to combine all the lines in the list into a single line. like this:

file1, file2, file3, etc

so that I can feed all the files into the 7z command line app at the same time.

Would anyone know how I can do this? Maybe a for loop of some sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer in another question, here [in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459288/1059127)

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
(SET file-list=)
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (7z-Compression-List.txt) DO (
CALL SET file-list=%%file-list%%, %%x
)
SET file-list=%file-list:~1%
ECHO file-list=%file-list%
```

It worked beautifully. This is a modified copy of [Magoo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459288/1059127), so feel free to upvote original author if you like this answer.

Comment: Your script leaves an space at the beginning of the line. Replace ~1 with ~2 to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Amir. I'll update the answer as soon as I get a chance to test the change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/hidden-features-of-windows-batch-files/374361#374361):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type 7z-Compression-List.txt') do (
<nul set /p Test=%%a, 
)
```

However it leaves an extra ", " at the end of line.

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks for the answer, the comma at the end doesn't work for me but it's always good to know alternative ways of doing things.